# ORA-00984: column not allowed here dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to run this sql script in oracle and get an error

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here.

```
declare
  tablename varchar2(200):='imagesroom';
  temp varchar2(50):='room_id';
  iid number:=1;
  dir varchar2(200):='imgdirroom';
  in_fname varchar2(100):='img1.jpg';
  obj ORDIMAGE;
  ctx RAW(64) := NULL;
begin
  execute immediate 'INSERT INTO '||tablename||'('||temp||',extension,icon) 
  VALUES(iid,'''',ORDImage(''FILE'',upper(dir),in_fname)) 
  RETURNING icon INTO obj';
end;
/   

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06512: at line 10
```

This one works great

```
INSERT INTO imagesroom(room_id,extension,icon) 
VALUES(iid,'',ORDImage('FILE',upper(dir),in_fname)) 
RETURNING icon INTO obj;
```

What's wrong with it?

if I do it this way

```
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO :table(:type,extension,icon) 
VALUES(:id,'''',ORDImage(''FILE'',upper(:dir),:fname)) RETURNING icon INTO obj' 
using tablename,temp,iid,dir,in_fname;
```

then

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00903: invalid table name
ORA-06512: at line 10
```

appear...

Comment: Related: [Why cannot I use bind variables in DDL/SCL statements in dynamic SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25489002/1461424)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, why the second insert inside a PL/SQL block works and *almost* the same insert executed dynamically using `execute immediate`  statement doesn't? Simply because of name resolution. When second insert, that `insert` statement which you've described as `this one works great` is being executed `iid` , `dir` and `in_fname` resolved to locally declared variables. And in case of the dynamically executed `insert` statement those  `iid` , `dir`  resolved to column names of the table you are trying to insert data into, and it's simply not allowed to put column names of a table you are trying to insert into in the `value` clause of an `insert` statement.  Use bind variables.

Secondly, about `returning into` clause. You need two of them. One as part of a dynamically formed `insert statement`(dynamic `returning into` clause) and one for `execute immediate` statement(static `returning into` clause), in order to get returning by the insert statement values out. Or, one dynamic `returning into` clause and one `OUT` bind variable(in this case).

To that end, your anonymous pl/sql block might look like this:

```
declare
  tablename  varchar2(200) :='imagesroom';
  temp       varchar2(50)  :='room_id';
  iid        number        :=1;
  dir        varchar2(200) :='imgdirroom';
  in_fname   varchar2(100) :='img1.jpg';
  obj        ORDIMAGE;
  ctx        RAW(64)       := NULL; -- really unnecessary, NULL by default.
  l_instr    varchar2(4000);
begin

  l_instr := 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename || '('||temp||',extension,icon) 
                VALUES(:1,'''',ORDImage(''FILE'',upper(:2), :3)) 
              RETURNING icon INTO :4';

  execute immediate l_instr 
    using iid, dir, in_fname  returning into obj;

end;
/
```

Comment: You can use `using iid, dir, in_fname, out obj` too - either works, so is there an advantage to using a second `returning` clause instead?

Comment: thanks, after I run this  `temp2:='img_'||temp||'.currval';
 execute immediate  'UPDATE '||tablename||' SET icon = obj WHERE img_id = '||temp2;` and it that sequences can't be used there, sequnce name is in temp2, it works in not dynamic, where is mistake?

Comment: @AlexPoole. Alex, returning into clause allows you to return a "*record*" into a variable of a record data type. You wont be able to do that using `using` clause and out-bind variable. In this particular situation(no "*record*" being returned by the DML statement) there is really no visible advantages to me, except you do not have to specify mode (OUT) for a bind variable in case you have to return more than one value into more than one out-bind variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `RETURNING INTO` clause should be outside the dynamic DML statement:

```
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO '||tablename||'('||temp||',extension,icon) 
  VALUES(iid,'''',ORDImage(''FILE'',upper(dir),in_fname))'
RETURNING icon INTO obj;
```

There's an example at the bottom of [this documentation site about EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm)

Comment: seemd so but doesn't work, 'cos returning isn't using for dml. this statement will return error about icon, if delete it, will appear previous error

Comment: @user2993505 Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

The `iid`, `dir`, `in_fname` and `obj` references inside the SQL string you're executing are literals, so they're being interpreted as column names. You should use bind variables (as shown in the [10g docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dynamic_sql.htm#sthref1119):

```
...
begin
  execute immediate 'INSERT INTO '||tablename||'('||temp||',extension,icon) 
  VALUES(:iid,'''',ORDImage(''FILE'',upper(:dir),:in_fname)) 
  RETURNING icon INTO :obj'
  USING iid, dir, in_fname, OUT obj;
end;
/
```

You can add something like

```
  dbms_output.put_line(obj.in_fname);
```

... to verify that `obj` is populated.